# Android - youtube api : Limitations policy & Pricing

Tags: android-youtube-api

I noticed that Android youtube api(YouTube Data API v3) limitation like these:

- units per day 50,000,000
- units per 100 seconds per user    300,000
- requests per 100 seconds  3,000,000

Is there any pricing information when exceeded those limitation? I found only Quota Extension request page(https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/)

Thanks in advance.